# Checkbox checked issue in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a grid view in which i have a textbox i am passing 0 and 1 to check box if it is 1 the checkbox to be checked.I tried but it is not working.Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Sales Price Ref" ItemStyle-Width="200px" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                             <HeaderTemplate>                                        
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSalesPriceRef" runat="server" Text="Sales Price"></asp:Label>
                                            <br /><br />
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSalesPriceRef" AutoPostBack="true" BorderStyle="Solid"   BorderColor="#6495ED" BackColor="#B0C4DE" Height="20px" Width="90px" OnTextChanged="txtItem_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                             </HeaderTemplate>   
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChSalesPriceRef" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("SalesPriceRef")=="1" ? true:false %>' />
                                <%-- <asp:TextBox ID="txtSalesPriceRef" Width="90px" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SalesPriceRef") %>'></asp:TextBox>--%>
                             </EditItemTemplate>                              
                             <ItemTemplate>                                              
                               <asp:Label ID="lblSalesPriceRef"  runat="server"  Text='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("SalesPriceRef"))== "1" ? "True" :"False" %>' > </asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>                                                                         
                          </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

YES you can achieve it by binding it to the checkbox

as

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ChSalesPriceRef" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("SalesPriceRef")%>' Enabled="false" />
```

if you allow to change checkbox value then make enable=true